# Test a React tag with dot notation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, semantic-ui-react

I have this simple react component that uses Semantic UI tags:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Card.Meta ref="CardStatusComponent123" className={'float small ' + this.props.align + this.props.statusClassName}>
        {this.props.statusText}
      </Card.Meta>
    );
  }
```

I have written a test in Jest and Enzyme to test the component:

```
describe('CardStatusComponent', () => {
  it('displays prop text', () => {
    const props = {
      statusText: 'Available',
      statusClassName: ' green ',
      align: 'left',
    };
    const wrap = shallow(<CardStatusComponent {...props} />);
    expect(wrap.find("Card.Meta").at(0).hasClass('green')).toEqual(true)
  });
});
```

The error I get when running jest is:

> Method “hasClass” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

I know for a fact that it is because the tag name is separated by a dot because if I replace the tag with a div tag, it works.  I've tried accessing just "Card" and "Meta" separately and I can't find anything on Google.

Can anyone please explain to me how to test a tag with dot notation in Jest and Enzyme?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dot notation. But I would try `expect(wrap.find("Card).dive().hasClass("green")).toEqual(true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `wrap.find("Card.Meta")` you're trying to find by [`displayName`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname) which is not "Card.Meta". 
 Do this instead:

```
import Card from "..."

...

expect(wrap.find(Card.Meta) ... )
```